# Was ist denn "Drinkability"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Die *[Süddeutsche](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/muenchen/oktoberfest-das-sind-die-sechs-wiesnbiere-1.3664022-6)*, an sich als eher konservative und auch handwerklich normalerweise gut gemachte Zeitung bekannt, schreibt in der diesjährigen Wiesnbier-Verkostung folgendes über ein Bier:

> "Ein Bier mit hoher Drinkability, grundehrliches Handwerk."

Man scheint "Trinkbarkeit" zu meinen, was auch immer das dann bedeuten mag.

dict.cc übersetzt das englische Wort als "Süffigkeit", was ich kenne, und was mir als gelegentlicher Biertrinker auch was sagt.

Ein britischer Kollege meint, das Wort bezeichne im Englischen sowohl die "Süffigkeit" eines Getränks, als auch die Eigenschaft des Trinkers selbst ("capacity to be drunk"). Das macht mir die Sache noch ein wenig suspekter.

[Dieser Artikel](http://www.cara-online.com/blog/beer-drinkability/) lässt darauf schließen, dass die Briten nichtmal selber wissen, was das sein soll.

Was genau soll dieses Lehnwort aussagen und warum braucht man ausgerechnet in Bayern ein englisches Wort, um etwas über Bier zu sagen?

Comment: Das BRAUCHT kein Mensch. Diese unsäglichen Anglizismen sind mir ein Graus...

Comment: Mich graut es jetzt schon vor denjenigen, die wieder argumentieren, dass das unsere Sprache bereichern würde und deshalb ein positiver Beitrag zum Sprachwandel wäre.

Comment: Damit wollte der Autor wohl besonders lustig und geistreich wirken, tatsächlich wirkt er damit aber ziemlich unprofessionell.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Im Gegenteil - Ich glaube nicht, dass die Absicht war, lustig oder geistreich zu sein. Der Rest des Artikels liest sich wie der ernste Bericht über eine noble Weinverkostung.

Comment: Ich finde ja, dass fremdsprachige Wörter unsere Sprache bereichern - von ihrem positiven Beitrag zum Sprachwandel ganz zu schweigen! Weiß nicht was du hast @BjörnFriedrich :D

Comment: Ich find's albern; aber Grausen finde ich zwei Oktaven zu hoch gegriffen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wer sich den verlinkten Text (bzw. die Bilderstrecke) genau anschaut, dem sollten eigentlich die Anführungszeichen auffallen, die in der Rubrik "Mit einem Satz" durchgehend vorhanden sind, aber in den anderen Rubriken fehlen. Offenbar handelt es sich hier *nicht* um eine Aussage des Autors der *Süddeutschen*, sondern um ein Zitat, wahrscheinlich von Herrn Stückle.

Comment: Im Kontext der jährlichen Münchner Touristenfalle und ihrer oftmals amerikanischen Besucher verständlich. Andererseits natürlich besonders schamvoll, dass nun ausgerechnet die Bayern sich den Preißn aus Übersee so andienen.

Comment: Ich halte es nicht für richtig, diese Frage mit der Begründung zu schließen, es gehe ausschließlich um fremdsprachliches Wissen. Wenn ein Wort in einem deutschen Satz wie ein deutsches Wort verwendet wird, also etwa der Großschreibung unterliegt und nicht (z. B. durch Kursivierung) als Fremdwort ausgezeichnet ist, dann ist es eingedeutscht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dieses Wort kommt eindeutig aus dem angelsächsischen Raum. Neben Wein wird neuerdings - beflügelt durch eine Budweiser-Werbekampagne - dort auch Bier mit einem *Drinkability*-Wert gemessen:

> [image]
>   <sup>Budweiser Werbung</sup>
>
> Drinkability is widely used as one of many attributes available to describe the characteristics of a beer. [...] A beer that has good drinkability is the one that invites the drinker to another glass.  <sup>[Master Brewers Association of the Americas](https://www.mbaa.com/publications/tq/tqPastIssues/2005/Abstracts/TQ-42-0013.htm)</sup>

Ein Bier mit einer guten "Drinkability" sei demnach ein Bier von dem man gerne noch ein zweites Glas trinkt.

Das Münchner Oktoberfest ist unstrittig ein sehr bierzentriertes Fest mit vorwiegend touristischem Publikum (auch aus dem angelsächsischen Raum). So liegt es auf der Hand, dass Braumeister Stückle, der in dem genannten Artikel zitiert wird, bei der Beschreibung seines Bieres auf diesen Begriff zurückgreift.

Comment: Ob sich jemand, der sich als "Bier-Sommelier" bezeichnen möchte, ausgerechnet einen Begriff, der von "Bud Light" geprägt wird, zu eigen machen muss, lasse ich mal dahingestellt. Danke für den Fund. Mir gefällt "Süffigkeit" weiterhin besser ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ja, *Drinkability* kann man mit *Trinkbarkeit* übersetzen, doch ich vermute mehr dahinter:

Eine Funktion der englischen Endung *-able* ist, den Wert von etwas auszudrücken: dass etwas in einer Hinsicht taugt (Vgl. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-able#Alternative_forms): “expressing capacity or worthiness in a passive sense”).
Dem entspricht z. B. die deutsche Endung *-wert*.

So steht für *drinkable* bei [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drinkable#English) sogar: “(of an alcoholic beverage, especially wine) Of good or satisfactory quality.”

*Drinkable*, einerseits trinkbar im wörtlichen Sinne (es ist flüssig, man kann es trinken), andererseits trinkbar im übertragenen Sinne (es schmeckt), wird dann nominalisiert: *drinkability*, nur dass die zweite Lesung, *gut schmecken*, dann nicht mehr natürlich klingt.